# Groovy script can't execute() external process

Tags: shell, groovy, command-line, apache-kafka

Main question: Would groovy's `execute()` method allow me to run a command that takes a file as an argument, any maybe run the command in background mode?

Here is my issue. I was able to use groovy's `execute()` for simple commands like `ls` for example. Suppose now I want to start a process like Kafka from a groovy script (end result is to replace `bash` files with groovy scripts). So I start with these lines:

```
def kafkaHome = "Users/mememe/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1"
def zkStart = "$kafkaHome/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh" 
def zkPropsFile = "$kafkaHome/config/zookeeper.properties"
```

Now, executing the command below form my mac terminal:

```
/Users/mememe/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /Users/mememe/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties
```

starts up the the process just fine. And, executing this statement:

```
println "$zkStart $zkPropsFile"
```

prints the above command line as is. However, executing this command from within the groovy script:

```
println "$zkStart $zkPropsFile".execute().text
```

simply hangs! And trying this:

```
println "$zkStart $zkPropsFile &".execute().text
```

where I make it a background process goes further, but starts complaining about the input file and throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/Users/mememe/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties"
```

Trying this gives the same exception as above:

```
def proc = ["$zkStart", "$zkPropsFile", "&"].execute()
println proc.text
```

What am I missing please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try using the `consumeProcessOutpusStream()` method:

```
def os = new File("/some/path/toyour/file.log").newOutputStream()
"$zkStart $zkPropsFile".execute().consumeProcessOutputStream(os)
```

You can find the the method in the Groovy docs for the `Process` class:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html

Which states:

> Gets the output and error streams from a process and reads them to keep the process from blocking due to a full output buffer. The stream data is thrown away but blocking due to a full output buffer is avoided. Use this method if you don't care about the standard or error output and just want the process to run silently - use carefully however, because since the stream data is thrown away, it might be difficult to track down when something goes wrong. For this, two Threads are started, so this method will return immediately.

Comment: Yep, this one worked. Now, how about going the extra mile and have this run as a background process so that other commands can be executed after it? I added a `&` so that we have `"$zkStart $zkPropsFile &"` but that didn't work. Or, should the code turn into a concurrent logic all together where the entire operation runs at the background, have it sleep a little, and run other processes in a different thread?

Comment: So, adding a `sleep SOMETIME` after your two lines and wrapping all lines inside a `Thread.start {...}.join()` clause gives the desired result, as following statements were executed successfully. Is there a better way?